# Why does this simple code not work?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why does this simple code not work? Cant end the php code with ?>. Using Wampserver 2.5. Nothing gets recorded in the db_words.
Have serched the internet for days but with no answers. 
It's simple, jus adding two words in words_db

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0       
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ORDLISTA</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Lägg till ord</h1>

<form action="addword.php" method="post">
Ord: <input type="text" name="ord"><br></br>
Förklaring: <input type="text" name="forklaring"><br></br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>



MY PHP CODE addword.php

<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","words_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ordlista (ord, forklaring)
VALUES ('$_POST[ord]', '$_POST[forklaring]');

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: I get more notice on line 11 and 12 in the php file. Yes i am a newbie.

Comment: yep, I knew that notice was going to come up. People don't listen when I say something.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `")` at the end

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ordlista (ord, forklaring)
VALUES ('".$_POST['ord']."', '".$_POST['forklaring']."')");
```

Comment: look again, you missed a few. these questions are off-topic.

Comment: It may be off topic & also he may be a beginner but it was a very minor mistake & easy to detect if that was the real problem.

Comment: if you get a downvote, it wouldn't have come from me. this won't resolve the question. wait for the OP; they'll say it *still* doesn't work.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\wamp\www\ord\addword.php on line 11

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\ord\addword.php on line 12

Comment: what was it that I said about 10 mins. ago?

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie to MySQLi. Can you be more specific or maybe correct the code for me. Maybe i am in the wrong forum. Seems not to be for beginners.

Comment: I don't get any warnings or errors now, but the words don't show up in the database.

Comment: Is it something in the VALUES("$_POST that's wrong?